# Custom Toggle Switch Settings Bundle

Tags: ios, xcode

I have scanned the docs regarding Settings Bundle on iOS and I could not figure out how to customize the values of a toggle switch. Instead of "ON" and "OFF", I would like it to become "LINE" and "BAR" for Chart Type option. Is this possible?

Any insights will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, you're pretty limited in the customization of the Settings bundle.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll just change the option label.

Answer (score 0):

you can not change the the "on/off" labels of the standard switch provided in interface builder.  If you want to stay with stock parts, then you can emulate a switch using a segment control - just use 2 segments.  You have to build the toggle logic out a bit yourself, but its pretty straight forward.

There are a few IOS control libraries that provide a UISwitch subclass that does allow you to change the titles. One that I've used that is pretty nicely done is RCSwitch.  You can find it here:  https://github.com/robertchin/rcswitch

hope that helps,
be well.

Comment: This all works like that in the regular app, not the Settings bundle as emmandroid's asking about.

Comment: gotcha, reading the entire question is generally a good idea :)